# How to show the host name in Linux commandline prompt

Tags: bash, prompt, hostname

I have several VMs and right now my command-line prompt looks like `-bash-3.2$`; identical on every VM, because it doesn't contain the host name.
I need to always see which VM I'm on using `hostname` before I do any operation. How can I add the host name to the shell prompt?

ENV:
CentOS/ssh

Comment: I always use a prompt where I can easily copy it for a scp-command, so it is `export PS1='\u@\h:\w \$ '`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just change the value of the `$PS1` environment variable:

```
PS1="\h$ "
```

where `\h` is replaced with the hostname. Add that to `/etc/bash.bashrc` to set it permanent.

Comment: It's simple but works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Look into your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`, there may be a commented prompt setup that should do what you want, like this one on our infra:

```
export PS1='\h:\w\$ '
```

Which looks like:

```
coolservername:~#
```

Or if you plan on logging as non-root, you can use:

```
 export PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

to add username before the hostname.

You can have fun adding colours, multiline or whatever info you want in the prompt, a quick search on "bash prompts" should give you plenty of hints.

Answer (score 8):

I like when the shell prompt shows the username, hostname and the name of the working directory. In addition, I like, when all of this is shown in colors. So I usually put

```
export PS1='\[\033[0;32m\]\u@\h:\[\033[36m\]\W\[\033[0m\] \$ '
```

in `~/.bashrc`. In order to apply changes immediately, call

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Also if you switch to root using `su` it is good to see bash prompt in a different color, so that you exercise extra caution. For this I add the line

```
export PS1='\[\033[0;31m\]\u@\h:\[\033[36m\]\W\[\033[0m\] \$ '
```

into `/root/.bashrc`. And call

```
. /root/.bashrc
```

to apply the changes. Then it looks like this

[image]

Very often VPS server admins provide dumb hostnames. In order to change it, open `/etc/sysconfig/network` and change the line

```
HOSTNAME=put_a_name_that_you_want_to_see_in_bash_prompt_here
```

If you want different colors for `username@host` part, you have to change `0;32m` part in the first example, or `0;31m` part in the second example. The list of available colors can be found [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html)

Since `.bashrc` is executed for non-login shells, do not forget to double check that

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
         . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

is present in `~/.bash_profile`, since `~/.bash_profile` is executed at your login. And also add the same piece into `/root/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

As well as changing prompt there is an option in the configuration of `konsole` and the gnome terminal emulator, that will change the title bar (or tab title).